# Internet browsing history

Tags: browser, browser-history, mobile-browser

Many of my friends use my cellphone and browse the Internet which uses mobile data (not a hotspot or WiFi). After that they delete their browser history. How do I know what they have browsed on my cellphone

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for questions related to programming, therefore you should look for a Stack Exchange site where this question is more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If they're deleting your browser history, then there is not a way to know what they've browsed. (That's basically the point of deleting history)

Maybe there are a sort of thirth party parental controls that allows you to view the history on a different way, but I do not know if such an app exists.

I think there are other workarounds though, like tell them that they should not use mobile data when they use your phone, or don't allow them on your phone at all if you're not feeling good about it.